# Download Entire Repository From Bintray

Tags: curl, download, wget, bintray, jcenter

Trying to download an entire repository from jcenter-bintray using wget is not working.
I have a private repository which i'm trying to download all it's artifacts following the jcenter sunset.

Running the command:`$wget --recursive -e robots=off --no-parent --reject "index.html*" --user=<MY_USERNAME> --password=<MY_PASSWORD> "https://dl.bintray.com/nanorep/"`

Results with a recursive call to download all the artifacts but with the wrong url for each artifact. Each artifact has an "/:" prefix which results with an 404 error:

`--2021-04-26 12:51:11--  https://dl.bintray.com/<PATH_TO_ARTIFACT>.zip Reusing existing connection to dl.bintray.com:443. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2021-04-26 12:51:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Why do i get the "/:" added to the artifacts url and how can i avoid it?